# How to disable a particular menu-item in antd inline menu?

Tags: antd, react-typescript

I am using Antd [menu](https://ant.design/components/menu)
I am new to antd and I was trying to disable a particular menu item and the menu is of type inline.
I see that MenuItem has disabled props but with inline type, I am not understanding how to disable a particular menu item.
Here is a code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0f31pw?file=/demo.tsx) link.
Any leads will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can disabled each menu item by passing `disabled:true`,

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique , we are passing the menu items in the items prop of menu. How can we set disabled:true to each menu item?

Comment: Check the Codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/inline-menu-antd-5-2-0-forked-cbls7w?file=/demo.tsx. I disable `Option 1` by passing `disabled: true`.

Answer (score 1):

change getItem function to this

```
function getItem(
      label: React.ReactNode,
      key: React.Key,
      icon?: React.ReactNode,
      children?: MenuItem[],
      type?: 'group',
      disabled?: boolean,
    ): MenuItem {
      return {
        key,
        icon,
        children,
        label,
        type,
        disabled
      } as MenuItem;
    }
```

and pass `disabled` argument

```
    getItem('Item 2', 'g2', null, [getItem('Option 3', '3'), getItem('Option 4', '4', null, null, null, true)], 'group'),
```

this will disable `option 4`